# having a problem with fillament many to many relationship, query cant find my category_id column

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-filament

Using laravel v9 and Filament v2
for my many to many relationship
Books and categories

this is the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value
INSERT INTO
  `books` (
    `image`,
    `title`,
    `author_id`,
    `publication_date`,
    `copies`,
    `updated_at`,
    `created_at`
  )
VALUES
  (
    Uqvz9qyKeqt11XmrlntLZuWWkgKYjT - metaNDAzNjI1ODg3XzE4MDU4MDc2MTY1MzUyNjdfOTIxNjYxODQ2MjE5MTc5ODE1OV9uLmpwZw = = -.jpg,
    AS,
    1,
    AS,
    AS,
    2023 -12 -13 16: 14: 00,
    2023 -12 -13 16: 14: 00
  )
```

'as' is my input as to test it

for my fillament form

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Card::make()
            ->schema([
                FileUpload::make('image')->image(),
                TextInput::make('title')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                select::make('author_id')   
                ->relationship('author', 'full_name')
                ->required(),
                Select::make('category_id')
                ->multiple()    
                ->relationship('categories', 'name')
                ->preload()
                ->required(),
                TextInput::make('publication_date')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                TextInput::make('copies')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255)
            ])
        ]);
    }
```

for my models

```
class Book extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;

        protected $fillable = ['author_id','image','category_id','title','language','publication_date','copies']; 

        protected $casts = [
            'category_id' => 'array',
        ];

        public function author(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
        } 

        public function categories(){
            return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
        }  
    }    `

`class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name']; 
        
    public function books(){
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }  
}
```

for my migration

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('author_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('image'); 
            $table->string('title'); 
            $table->string('publication_date');
            $table->string('copies');    
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I tried a lot of ways but cant seem to work it out
im expecting it to be saved to my database as an array as it is a many to many rellationship
so i can show it in filament table

[sample input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnLWh.png)

[category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4my5R.png)

[book table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc79x.png)

Comment: It can find the table just fine. It's tell you that `category_id` on `books` doesn't have a default value. When you're creating a new book, you're not passing in the category ID

Comment: im filling in the category_id select form 
ex 
academic
fiction
comedy

which in their own table is id 1 = fiction
and so on

Comment: Where are you actually saving the book?

Comment: yes, the other field works fine and can be saved in the books table when i turn the category_id column nullable to test it

Comment: Can you please show the code that actually saves the book? That's very important to your question.

Comment: its already posted, the form builder.
im using filament

Comment: That looks like the code to build the form, not to save the record.

Comment: im using the filament package
that is the code to save a records inside the database
https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#select

Answer (score 4):

As per your table design, this will not work.

You have added a `belongsToMany` relationship.
However, it should be this way

Models\Book.php

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Models\Category.php

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

In this case, you can assign only one category at a time to Book.

If you want to assign multiple categories to a book, then create a pivot table `book_category`
and in the relationship you need to add the following changes

Models\Book.php

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Models\Category.php

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

and then in your select input will work with this

```php
Select::make('category_id')
   ->multiple()    
   ->relationship('categories', 'name')
   ->preload()
   ->required(),
```

More reference,

V2: https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#populating-automatically-from-a-relationship

V3: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/select#integrating-with-an-eloquent-relationship